# How to read data sent by HTTParty in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to have two separate Ruby programs to communicate, one with the Sinatra gem, and another with the HTTParty gem. What I am attempting to do is post data to the Sinatra program from a HTTP post request in the other program.

This is the code that sends the data.

```rb
HTTParty.post('https://notgivingawaymydomain/post_data', {something: foo})
```

However, I don't know how to receive the data on the other end. I've tried a few things I researched on the internet but none seem to work.

EDIT

My code on the other end is really nothing special at the moment, but I'll put what I've been trying.

```rb
post '/post_data' do 
   #not sure how to access the hash that my post request sent here
end
```

Comment: _"I've tried a few things"_ – show your code (the one on the other end), so we know what's wrong. You probably don't want a Sinatra tutorial as an answer :-)

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the tip. :) I'm new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post data is available in the `params` object inside your Sinatra route:

```
post '/post_data' do 
  data = params["something"] # => my_value is now 'foo' in this example
  #... rest of code
end
```

Sinatra only parses the data if it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which it is in this case) or `multipart/form-data`. If you wanted to POST another type (e.g. JSON) you would need to parse the request body yourself using `request.body`:

```
post '/json_data'
  # request.body is an IO object
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
end
```

---

Be sure to get the syntax of your `HTTParty` call correct. You need to specify the `body:` key of the options:

```
HTTParty.post('http://localhost:4567/post_data', body: {something: "foo"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was missing the `body:` key. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post data via HTTP you need a web-server on the receiving end.

sinatra describes itself as `Sinatra is a DSL for quickly creating web applications in Ruby with minimal effort`

so in itself it is not a webserver, but it can be run through a webserver to process the data that you post via HTTP. it is bundled with a webserver, so you can start it right away.

if you look at the sinatra [README](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html) it says

> It is recommended to also run gem install thin, which Sinatra will pick up if available.

thin is a reliable webserver that is recommended to run sinatra web applications.

Comment: I do indeed have a webserver on the other end, I'm just not sure how to access the passed hash. 

Thank you for your response, though. :)